# Max. number of subqueries with WHERE clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rdbms

What is the value of maximum number of sub-queries that can be written in WHERE clause?
Is it dependent on the RDBMS or the number of attributes of the table?

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL standard does not specify a maximum number of subqueries in the `where` clause.
Any such limitation, if exits, would be RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 0):

As already said by Murenik, there is no such limitation from ANSI standard but specific RDBMS may restrict like

[SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx) says

> Up to 32 levels of nesting is possible, although the limit varies
>   based on available memory and the complexity of other expressions in
>   the query. Individual queries may not support nesting up to 32 levels.

[MySQL doesn't say anything about any such limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/limits003.htm) Says

> Subqueries:   Maximum levels of subqueries in a SQL statement
>   : Unlimited in the FROM clause of the top-level query